# Line between table row with image HTML

Tags: html, css, html-email

It seems to work fine in outlook and iCloud but shows the line in both yahoo and Gmail. This seems to be a common issue, but all answers I found do not work for me. This is my first experience with HTML emails.

[image: this is how it shows in yahoo and gmail]

```html
<body>
  <center>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse;border-style:none;margin:auto;max-width:640px;">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td valign="top" width="100%">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;border-collapse:collapse;border-style:none;margin:auto;max-width:640px;font-size:0em;">
              <tbody>
                <tr>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" colspan="2" style="font-size: 0px;">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://tmmcscdn.azureedge.net/RdXp8J5xGyF483sTwWagA/Banner.jpg" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;" height="150" width="640">
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td valign="top" width="420" style="font-size: 0px;">
                    <span>
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </span>
                  </td>
                  <td valign="top" width="220" style="font-size: 0px;">
                    <div>
                      <img src="https://tmmcscdn.azureedge.net/RdXp8J5xGyF483sTwWagA/ProfLiability_NSO.png" width="220" height="32" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;">
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </center>
</body>
```

Comment: I transformed your code block into a snippet, and it does not recreate the issue. So it only recreates the issue in yahoo and gmail?

Comment: `<center>` tag is obsolete

Comment: yeah only in those 2 all others so far seem to be good.

Comment: @MisterJojo The OP is using it for email where it (for some reason) still exists

Comment: the center tag still working. i did try removing it for the heck for it and nothing changed.

Comment: the OP? not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @logan it means original poster. That's you. But anyways, don't all emails behave differently when it comes to accepting html/css code? I used to do some and each platform would alter a little bit of it.

Comment: @logan OP = Original Poster. In this case, you

Comment: @brandon yes the do act differently when it comes to accepting HTML and CSS but from what i read as long as the CSS is written in-line it does not matter,

Answer (score 1):

The `<div>` may be interfering. There's no need for it. Also, if you want zero spacing, use line-height with font-size.

That is:

```
<tr>
  <td valign="top" width="420" style="font-size: 0px;line-height:0;"></td>
  <td valign="top" width="220" style="font-size: 0px;line-height:0;"><img src="https://tmmcscdn.azureedge.net/RdXp8J5xGyF483sTwWagA/ProfLiability_NSO.png" width="220" height="32" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;"></td>
</tr>
```